# Can you use the Improved Two-Weapon Feint feat in tandem with the Sword and Pistol feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, ranged-attack, melee-combat

I've been trying to find a viable way to use the [Sword and Pistol](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/sword-and-pistol-combat/) feat, and I thought about using the [Two-Weapon Feint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-feint-combat/) feat (more specifically, [its improved version](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-two-weapon-feint-combat/)).

Two-Weapon Feint states that you have to use melee attacks, which I tend to believe is worded to prevent feinting from a range (such as with throwing weapons like a dagger). Sword and Pistol would help me fire in combat and not get hit by attacks of opportunity.

That being said, I'm still confused regarding whether I could use a rapier to feint, then use my crossbow to attack to take advantage of the lowered AC.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going strictly for rules as written, the answer would be no, as two weapon feint specifically says melee attacks.  However some gm's may house rule it to work.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can

The [Two-Weapon Feint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-feint-combat/) feat has only two requirements:

- 1) *"While using Two-Weapon Fighting to make melee attacks"*. If you are using your melee weapon to make melee attacks, then this requirement is met;
- 2) *"you can forgo your first primary-hand melee attack"*, which can be done if your primary hand is wielding a melee weapon.

So, when making a *Full Attack* with a sword and pistol, for example, you could *spend* the first sword attack to make a *Feint* maneuver against an opponent within your melee reach. Then make an attack with your pistol, as described under [Sword and Pistol](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/sword-and-pistol-combat/), and then proceed from there normally.

You simply couldn't do this if your primary hand was wielding a ranged weapon, or if both of your weapons are ranged weapons.

### There are ways to *Feint* with ranged weapons

The [Ranged Feint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ranged-feint-combat/) feat (*Ultimate Intrigue*) allows you to use the *Feint* maneuver with ranged weapons, using *the same action used to feint*:

> Benefit(s): **You can feint with a ranged weapon** by throwing a thrown weapon or firing one arrow, bolt, bullet, or other piece of ammunition; **this feint takes the same action as normal to feint**, but depending on your weapon, you might have to reload or draw another weapon afterward. When you successfully use a ranged feint, you deny that enemy its Dexterity bonus to AC against your ranged attacks as well as your melee attacks for the same duration as normal. If your feints normally deny a foe its Dexterity bonus to AC against attacks other than your own, this applies only against others’ melee attacks.
>
> Normal: You can feint only with a melee weapon, and only against a creature you threaten with that weapon.

Similarly, the [Feint from Shadows](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/feint-from-shadows-ex) rogue talent (*Blood of Shadows* player companion) allows the same, but you must be concealed and within 30 feet of your target.

Which, in most situations, means using a *Standard action*. But if you figure out ways to feint using an attack that doesn't say specifically that it must be with a melee weapon (ie: not [Two-Weapon Feint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-feint-combat/)), then you could also make ranged feints during your attack sequence.

I can only think of one feat that could do something like this, [Out of the Sun](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/out-of-the-sun-teamwork/), but it is a teamwork feat and the benefits are applied to your ally. However, that doesn't mean that there aren't other ways to achieve it.

Comment: "melee attacks" implies plural, wouldn't you need to be able to perform two weapon fighting normally with the weapon set first?